# Modify price of all product using event observer

Tags: module, event-observer, magento-1, product-prices, custom-prices

I made module to add `100 USD` to all products price using module, but it does not work as expected. Need help to fix it.

Below is my event observer xml code:

```
<catalog_product_collection_load_after>
            <observers>
                <setname>
                    <type>model</type>
                    <class>Mdoule_Customgroup_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>modifyall</method>
                </setname>
            </observers>
</catalog_product_collection_load_after>
```

and **modifyall** function is as below:

```
    public function modifyall(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
        $products = $observer->getCollection();
        foreach( $products as $product )
        {
            $originalprice = $product->getPrice();
            $customprice = $originalprice+ 100;
            $product->setPrice($customprice);
            $product->setCustomPrice($customprice);
            $product->setOriginalCustomPrice($customprice);
        }
   }
```

that works fine but i get price like below:

$1,450 $1,550

Comment: can you tell me what is display  current price?

Comment: it show 1550 with line over and also 1450 i just want 1550

Comment: i think you print both price $originalprice as well as $customprice on phtml file.

Comment: You want to show special and regular price ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have tested your code and modified it use below :

```
  public function modifyall(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
        $products = $observer->getCollection();
        foreach( $products as $product )
        {
            $originalprice = $product->getPrice();
            $customprice = $originalprice+ 100;
            $product->setPrice($customprice);
            $product->setCustomPrice($customprice);
            $product->setOriginalCustomPrice($customprice);
            $product->setFinalPrice($customprice);
        }
   }
```

Comment: can u help me with : http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/106068/bundled-product-allowing-product-with-required-options